# Radio Button and Checkbox labels positioning

Tags: html, css

I have a form in which the radio buttons and checkboxes look like this:
[image]

I would like to know if I can get rid of the distance between the buttons and their labels in some way. I also like to to move the buttons to the leftmost side of the form. Almost under the question number.

This is currently the CSS to my radio buttons:

```
.radio{
direction: ltr;
  padding: 0 5px 0 0px;
  display: block;
  clear: left;
  float: left;
}
```

Also my whole form works under a  called stylized with a css as the following if it helps:

```
/* ----------- stylized ----------- */
#stylized{
    border:solid 2px #b7ddf2;
    background:#ebf4fb;
}
#stylized h1 {
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-bottom:8px;
}

#stylized p{
    font-size:11px;
    color:#666666;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    border-bottom:solid 1px #b7ddf2;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
#stylized label{
    display:block;   
    text-align:right;
    width:140px;
    float:left;
}
#stylized link {
    font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    color:#333333;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #FFA500;
}
#stylized .small{
    color:#666666;
    display:block;
    font-size:11px;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-align:right;
    width:140px;
}
#stylized input{
    float:left;
    font-size:12px;
    padding:4px 2px;
    border:solid 1px #aacfe4;
    width:200px;
    margin:2px 0 20px 10px;
    background-color: #EEE8AA
}
#stylized input:active { background: #FF7F00 !important; color: black; }
#stylized input:focus { background: yellow; color: black; }

#stylized select{
    float:left;
    font-size:12px;
    padding:4px 2px;
    border:solid 1px #aacfe4;
    width:205px;
    margin:2px 0 20px 10px;
    background-color:#C1FFC1;
    direction: ltr
}


#date select{
    float:left;
    font-size:10px;
    padding:4px 2px;
    border:solid 1px #aacfe4;
    width:60px;
    margin:2px 0 20px 10px;
    background-color:#FFDAB9
}


#stylized textArea{
    float:left;
    font-size:10px;
    font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    padding:4px 2px;
    border:solid 1px #aacfe4;
    width:330px;
    height:100px;
    margin:2px 0 20px 10px;
    background-color: #EEDD82
}
#stylized textarea:active { background: #FF7F00 !important; color: black; }
#stylized textArea:focus { background: yellow; color: black; }
```

Comment: One can only guess if you dont give the html source of that form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to work with css styling issues, is to open the page in Google Chrome, then right click on the section in question, and click "Inspect Element". Then you will see the css that is responsible for what you selected on the right side style display. You can change these items from there without reloading the page.

So what I recommend for you is to do that, then on the `display: block;` that is in the right side display, change it to `display: none;`. You can make minor changes like this throughout until you get the look you want then update your actual css.

Comment: Thank you very much! Google Chrome has just become my number one CSS debugger.

Comment: @Pedram Just keep in mind that different browsers render css differently; so from time to time view it in other browsers. Internet Explorer varies from version to version too, so when your in IE, press F12 and you can set different browser modes to see how everything looks and behaves.

Answer (score 0):

You have your labels text-aligned right:

```
#stylized label{
  display:block;   
  text-align:right;
  width:140px;
  float:left;
}
```

So, the text is aligning right to its container.

Comment: I'm confused - if you want it to align to the left (ie, removing that gap) set it to text-align: left. If your container is 140px wide, and you set text-align to right, it's going to do just that.

Comment: yes you are right @geebru but actually i realized if i remove some unnecessary css that was causing these problems i was more comfy with the default. but your answer is correct. i also had no idea how google chrome's inspect element can help you trace your code and find the problem.

Comment: Chrome's inspector thrives in the sense that you can remove, alter, or add CSS in the browser inspect element area to test what is causing issues. You can then make the edits you made in inspect element in your actual files.